# How are safety/liveness languages defined on the set of finite or infinite words?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, model-checking, program-verification, formal-methods

Let $Σ$ be an alphabet (e.g., the powerset of atomic propositions coming from some Kripke structure, though such details are irrelevant here).

For *infinite* words, a language $P\subseteq Σ^ω$ is called a ***safety*** language iff every word $σ ∈ Σ^ω \setminus P$ has a finite prefix $σ̂$ such that $P ∩ \{σ' ∈ Σ^ω \mid σ̂\ \text{is a prefix of}\ σ'\} = ∅$.

1. Is there an accepted, *meaningful* definition of safety languages for *finite* words, i.e., "A set $P\subseteq Σ^*$ is called a safety language iff …"?
2. Is there an accepted, *meaningful* definition of safety languages for *finite or infinite* words, i.e., "A set $P\subseteq Σ^ω ∪ Σ^*$ is called a safety language iff …"?

For *infinite* words, a language $P\subseteq Σ^ω$ is called a ***liveness*** language iff each finite word from $Σ^*$ is a prefix of a word from $P$.

3. Is there an accepted, *meaningful* definition of liveness languages for *finite* words, i.e., "A set $P\subseteq Σ^*$ is called a liveness language iff …"?
4. Is there an accepted, *meaningful* definition of liveness languages for *finite or infinite* words, i.e., "A set $P\subseteq Σ^ω ∪ Σ^*$ is called a liveness language iff …"?

In cases 2 and 4, the definitions for finite-or-infinite words should be (intuitively speaking) compatible with the standard definitions for infinite words.

Of course, some folks prefer to speak about safety/liveness *properties*, which are predicates $(W)→\{0,1\}$, rather than about safety/liveness *languages*, which are subsets of $W$, where $W$ is the corresponding set of words ($Σ^ω$, $Σ^*$, or $Σ^ω∪Σ^*$). For this question, the preferred framework (predicates on the powerset vs. subsets) is irrelevant.

Needless to say: in case of a negative answer, please substantiate your concerns.

Crosspost: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/115156

Comment: Given a set of infinite words, you can construct the set of finite prefixes of those words. And given a set of finite words, you can build the set of infinite words that have infinitely many prefixes in the set. I think I've seen safety and liveness defined on sets of finite words in such a way that those two constructions preserved safety and liveness. I think it was in a Master 1 course though so it's possible it was introduced just to avoid speaking about infinite words.

Comment: I did understand it. And if you call f the function that takes a language of finite words and returns the language of infinite words that have infinitely many prefixes in that language, then "f(L) is a safety language" is a correct definition for safety on languages of finite words, and you can rephrase it to not mention infinite words.

Comment: Using f also works for liveness. I can't see any reasonable way to define it on languages with both finite and infinite words, other than defining g that applies f to the sublanguage of finite words and returns the union of that and the sublanguage of infinite words. But both definitions I described can't really bring anything new: in both cases, the language of finite words is just used to represent a language of infinite words, and aside from the representation, nothing changes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes to all questions, so it is enough to answer 2 and 4, as the definitions work in particular for languages of finite words:

- 2. A language $P\subseteq \Sigma^*\cup\Sigma^\omega$ is safety if whenever $u\notin P$, then $u$ has a finite prefix $u'\in\Sigma^*$ such that for any word $v$, $u'v\notin P$.
- 4. A language $P\subseteq \Sigma^*\cup\Sigma^\omega$ is liveness if for any finite word $u\in\Sigma^*$, there is a word $v$ such that $uv\in P$.